# Datagrid row height doesnot shrink back

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a data grid, in each row I have one cell which needs to have a very lengthy text which is about 1000 characters long. So I decided to put the text in the expander control keeping the cell width fixed, when the user wants to read the text, he clicks on the expander to open and reads it.

The row height automatically grows when the expander is expanded but when the expander is collapsed back, the row height doesnt shirk. Can anyone pls tell me how to set the row height back after the expander is collapsed?

i tried the follwing link.
http://forums.silverlight.net/forums/p/133177/299186.aspx#299186
 but  this  did not work

any help would be grealty appreciated,
 thanks

Answer (score 0):

i was not able  to solve this problem using  SL  control.

alternate  solution to this is use   silverlight telerik  grid  control. where we can solve the problem.